# How can I initialize a shared memory array with an existing NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I would like to access an existing NumPy array from a subprocess using the `multiprocessing` module without copying the array to a shared memory object. Apparently, `multiprocessing.Array` creates such a shared memory array, but I can't seem to be able to point the array to an existing `numpy.ndarray` object. This is critical, because the existing array can be quite large (up to a couple of GB), so I definitely need to avoid any copy operations.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np


def f(x, idx):
    """Dummy function to manipulate an array."""
    x[idx] = 999


a = np.array([1.2, 15.8, 10.3, 7.4, -44.9])
b = mp.Array("d", a)  # apparently this creates a copy of a in b
print("Original array:".rjust(28, " "), a)

f(a, 0)
print("Change a[0] in main process:".rjust(28, " "), a)

p = mp.Pool(1)

p.apply_async(f, args=(b, 4))
print("Change b[4] in subprocess:".rjust(28, " "), np.frombuffer(b.get_obj()))
```

Ideally, I'd like `a` and `b` refer to the same underlying numbers, but apparently this is not working. Interestingly, `b` is also not changed by `p.apply_async(f, args=(b, 4))` - this is probably not related to the original question, but I'd still like to understand why.

Comment: Let me know if this thing worked :D

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, since in this question `unshared_arr` and `arr` do not refer to the same address in memory, which is exactly what I'd like to do.

Comment: From  the docs it looks like `mp.Array` creates a `ctypes` array in shared memory, and initializes it from values in `a`.  It isn't storing or sharing a pointer to the `a` object.  So `b` is not just a copy, it's not a numpy array; it's a different kind of data structure. Note in the docs it can intialized from a `range`, a `list` and `Array.array`.

Comment: Something went wrong with marking this as a duplicate - the wrong question is linked, could someone please correctly link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037545/create-shared-memory-around-existing-array-python?